# Odd "Class not found when unmarshalling" error

Tags: android, unmarshalling, parcelable, galaxy

So I encountered a strange *Class not found when unmarshalling* error in my app. Everytime I fire up an activity with parcelable object in the intent I get this error but everything seems to work fine.  I wrote a simple app to test parcels and this error. The app has one button which launches new activity with following code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), Display.class);
    Data data = new Data(49, "Foobar");
    i.putExtra("data", data);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

When I tap the button I get looong error/stacktrace which you'll find in the bottom of this post. The interesting thing is that I don't even need to handle the bundle/parcel/data in the new activity to get this error. I'm starting to belive that my phone(Galaxy S3 LTE) f*cks with the parcel somehow since I haven't been able to reproduce this error with emulator or S2.

Has anyone else encountered this behaviour or have some ideas how I could try to fix this?

The parcel object I use is the following:

```
public class Data implements Parcelable {
    private int mNumber;
    private String mText;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeInt(mNumber);
        dest.writeString(mText);
    }
    public Data(Parcel in) {
        mNumber = in.readInt();
        mText = in.readString();
    }
    public static final Creator<Data> CREATOR = new Creator<Data>() {
        @Override
        public Data createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Data(source);
        }
        @Override
        public Data[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Data[size];
        }
    };
    public int getNumber() {
        return mNumber;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return mText;
    }
    public Data(int num, String s) {
        mNumber = num;
        mText = s;
    }
}
```

and the error:

```
10-20 22:15:22.605    2378-2389/? E/DatabaseUtils﹕ Writing exception to parcel
    java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13101)
            at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
            at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
            at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
            at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
10-20 22:15:22.610    2378-2997/? E/Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: com.foobar.parceltest.Data
    java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.foobar.parceltest.Data
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
            at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
            at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
            at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4981)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3163)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3119)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:157)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2115)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/foobar/parceltest/Data
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
            at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
            at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
            at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4981)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3163)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3119)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:157)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2115)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.foobar.parceltest.Data" on path: .
            at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:64)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
            at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
            at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:204)
            at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:169)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2091)
            at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2055)
            at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1971)
            at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2255)
            at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
            at android.os.Bundle.getString(Bundle.java:1082)
            at android.content.Intent.getStringExtra(Intent.java:4961)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityLocked(ActivityStack.java:3761)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityStack.startActivityMayWait(ActivityStack.java:4981)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivityAsUser(ActivityManagerService.java:3163)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:3119)
            at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:157)
            at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2115)
            at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Comment: I've also seen this. And in a Galaxy S3 as well.